# Fragile error on robust command using relsize

Tags: hyperref, errors, sections-paragraphs

I created a supposedly robust command through `\DeclareRobustCommand{\plusplus}{\relsize{-3}{++}}` that modifies some `++` sign, and I use it in the document. However, when I use the `\relsize` and the `hyperref` package with the `tocdepth` counter set, I obtain a cryptic error (at least for me)

> Runaway argument? {\@tempcnta >\z@ \relax \advance \@tempcnta \m@ne
>   \@tempdimb  ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory
>   size=10000000].  ...\@tempcnta \m@ne \@tempdimb \@tempa 
>                                                     \@tempdimb \relax  l.15 \subsubsection{test\plusplus}

I even try to increase the memory size, as you can see, up to 10000000. And, in my full document the error changes to

> Runaway definition?
>   ->\protect 5.3.4 test\protect \<>-\kernel@ifnextchar [4]\<>-\@ifnextchar \ETC . ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory
>   size=10000000].  \new@ifnex
>                             tchar l.108 \subsection{test\plusplus}

I don't understand why the error changes. However, the code below is the shortest code I get before removing the error. However, I need to use the `hyperref` package and the table of contents. How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{relsize}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\plusplus}{\relsize{-3}{++}}

\usepackage{hyperref}%remove hyperref and it compiles

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}%or remove teh tocdepth and it compiles
%but use both and it doesn't

\tableofcontents

\subsubsection{test\plusplus}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with `hyperref` that tries to expand `\plusplus` and finds itself in an infinite loop.

Solution: provide a special definition of `\plusplus` for the bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\plusplus}{\relsize{-3}{++}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\plusplus{++}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%%% the following would work also without \pdfstringdefDisableCommands
\section{test\texorpdfstring{\plusplus}{++}}

\section{test\plusplus}

\end{document}
```

For a "one shot" occurrence, using `\texorpdfstring{\plusplus}{++}` is simpler. The `\pdfstringDisableCommands` way is better as it doesn't require thinking whether a command is safe for the bookmarks or not.

---

You can define `\plusplus` differently, without `relsize`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\plusplus}{%
  {\check@mathfonts\fontsize{\ssf@size}{\f@baselineskip}\selectfont++}%
}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\plusplus{++}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%%% the following would work also without \pdfstringdefDisableCommands
\section{test\texorpdfstring{\plusplus}{++}}

\section{test\plusplus}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to raise the two + symbols, you can change the definition into

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\plusplus}{%
  \raisebox{.25ex}{\check@mathfonts\fontsize{\ssf@size}{\f@baselineskip}\selectfont++}%
}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\plusplus{++}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: However, if I use the string it would put the ++ sign as is. The whole idea of the macro is to resize and shift the ++. However, for the sake of being MWE I removed that part. Hence, how can I ensure the command being called (or at least getting the desired effect) and not getting into an infinite loop?

Comment: @adn I've added also a different definition without `\relsize` and an easy way for shifting the + up. There's really no way to cope with complicated constructions and the bookmarks without resorting to `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`. Having smaller and raised + symbols in the bookmarks is impossible (unless you find a suitable Unicode character), because those are simply strings, not typeset boxes.