# hyperref option pdfusetitle with thanks

Tags: hyperref, metadata

What is the cleanest way to set the title in the document and in the PDF metadata (while not [repeating myself](http://wiki.c2.com/?DontRepeatYourself)) when also using `\thanks`?

This solution produces an incorrect Title metadata, that includes the content of the `\thanks` (or warnings from `hyperref`: “Token not allowed in a PDF string” when not using `\maketitle`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{The title\thanks{Thanks}}
\maketitle
Hello.
\end{document}
```

Therefore I have considered the following “solution” (rather a workaround, I’d say).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{The title}
\title{\mytitle\thanks{Thanks}}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\mytitle}
\maketitle
Hello.
\end{document}
```

But this clutters my document and is not elegant, especially because I can’t hide it in a preamble.
Is it possible instead, and would it be cleaner, to patch the way `pdfusetitle` works? Or is there perhaps some other workaround?

Comment: What prevents you from sticking from `\newcommand{}...\hypersetup{}` in the preamble for your workaround?

Comment: @aoi I want to hide those complexities (in a different sub-document `\include`d in the main document) from the redactor, who would only have to deal with the main document. Putting these three lines in that sub-document does not work as the redactor now has to open the sub-document to specify the title inside the `\newcommand{\mytitle}{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hyperref` defines the command `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` that can be used to redefine certain problematic commands for use in pdfstrings. With

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\thanks\@gobble
}
```

you can completely remove/ignore `\thanks` in pdfstrings. With

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\thanks#1{ (#1)}%
}
```

you would add the argument of `\thanks` in parentheses.

See also [\texorpdfstring for a full book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193947/35864) and [Fragile error on robust command using relsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106346/35864).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\thanks\@gobble
}

\begin{document}
\title{The title\thanks{Thanks}}
\maketitle
Hello.
\end{document}
```

[image: Metadata show "The title" as title, the title is "The title*" with a "thanks" footnote]

Note how it is not necessary to enclose the code in `\makeatletter...\makeatother` as usually required when working with macros with `@` in their name (cf. [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/35864)). `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` applies some trickery to avoid the explicit catcode changes, but that trick does not work when `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` is used as argument of another command, in that case you must wrap everything into `\makeatletter...\makeatother`, e.g.

```
\newtoggle{LCpres}
\togglefalse{LCpres}
\makeatletter
\iftoggle{LCpres}
  {\usepackage{hyperref}}
  {\usepackage[hypertexnames=false, pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
   \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\thanks\@gobble}}
\makeatother
```

For more complicated constructions there is `\texorpdfstring`, which could be used as `\texorpdfstring{The title\thanks{Thanks}}{The title}` with repetitions.

For different use cases something like [Redefine \title for possibility of a forced line breaking in a predefined place](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466095/35864) might also be possible.

Comment: Brilliant. But it does not play well with `iftoggle`, any idea why?
`\newtoggle{LCpres}
\togglefalse{LCpres}
\iftoggle{LCpres}{
 \usepackage{hyperref}
}{
 \usepackage[hypertexnames=false, pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
 \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
  \let\thanks\@gobble
 }
}`

Comment: @OlivierCailloux Could you open a new question with complete MWE about that, please?

Comment: @OlivierCailloux Got it! You'll need `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.

Comment: Usually `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is always needed when one uses macros with `@` in their name like `\@gobble`. But `hyperref` tries to be a user friendly and defines `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` in such a way that `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is not necessary. The trick used to do that, however, only works when `pdfstringdefDisableCommands` is not passed as argument to a different macro.

Comment: Bug report [introduced](https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues/81).